# How to play any video with a fixed frame rate (fps) using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

Is there any way or function in OpenCV that allows us to play any video with a fixed frame rate(fps)? Different videos may have different frame rates but by using OpenCV library can we play them by a fixed frame rate that we define?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this article](http://nashruddin.com/how_to_play_avi_files_with_opencv). It shows how to play back AVI files with OpenCV. Here, the frame rate is read using

```
int fps = ( int ) cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS );
```

and the delay is set via

```
key = cvWaitKey( 1000 / fps );
```

Hence, by controlling the `fps` variable, you can get the play back rate you want.

Comment: Surely that assumes that the reading/displaying of the frame takes no time and that cvWaitKey waits exactly the specified value? (in the docs it says that is only a minimum)

Comment: @Tim 1. Reading/displaying takes some time, but to have desired FPS one should only has to care about interval (delay) between consecutive reads (or displays). Frame will be displayed later (by some unknown read+display delay), but the next frame will (in average) be delayed by the same (unknown amount of time) and it's perfectly fine. 2. To account for delay inaccuracy, one adjusts next dealy depending on current time and desired next display time. For FPS of 30 this will result in frames being shown e.g. at moments 0, 31, 68, 99 ms i.e. close to ideal 0, 33, 67, 100

Answer (score 2):

```
int fps = (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
int delay = 1000 / fps;

while (true) {
    clock_t startTime = clock();

    capture.read(frame);
    process();

    imshow("video", frame);

    while (clock() - startTime < delay) {
        waitKey(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the while loop I added also a capture to skip the un-necessary frames; so that some frames are skipped